# Number of neurons in the input layer of a feedforward neural network

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, regression

I am a beginner in `Machine Learning`, and doing the multiclass `multiclass classsification task` of predicting the wine quality (0 to 10), based on 11 input variables
How do I decide the number of neurons in the input layer of my feedforward `neural network`?
For example, 11 variables in my dataset. 
In the input layer should I keep 11 neurons?
How about having more/less than 11 neurons?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it not a classification problem?

Comment: Yes it's a multiclass classification problem. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

**Input units**:
The question asks how many neurons should there be in the input layer. You have  11 variables. Therefore with the bias unit you will have a total of 12 units in the input layer.

**Output units**:
The number of output units will be determined by if it is a regression or a classification problem, and how many outputs does the problem have. For example for the wine dataset there would be 3 classes. In a one-hot encoding scheme, there would be 3 output units, one for each class.

The input and output units are therefore determined by the dataset (unless you are doing something crazy).

**Hidden layers and units**:
The number of hidden layers, and number of units per hidden layer is something which has to be tuned. For this specific problem, it might not be necessary to go much deep. One single hidden layer would do. Although, for smaller datasets you could train multiple models with different hidden units and different number of layers and select the model based on validation set score or based on cross-validation.

Trained with one hidden layer with 5 hidden units, three outputs. Wine dataset.
[image: Trained with one hidden layer with 5 hidden units, three outputs. Wine dataset.]

Trained with two hidden layers, with 10 and 5 hidden units respectively.
[image: Trained with two hidden layers, with 10 and 5 hidden units respectively.]

In both the cases the bias units are present. In my case this specific wine dataset have 13 inputs, and three outputs for a three class classification.

As this can be time consuming for larger datasets, you might use some heuristics to select the the number of layers. Eg. start with one hidden layer and, say, 5 units. Then train the model. Next, use 10 units and train another model, continue adding 5 units, and training models until the validation score does not improve much. Then stop adding units to the layer. Afterwards, you might want to add another layer and again change the number of hidden units and continue.

This is a very basic method. I would recommend you to read scholarly articles for effective methods. There are plenty of methods used. For a start I would like to point you here: [http://www.ml4aad.org/literature-on-neural-architecture-search/](http://Literature%20on%20Neural%20Architecture%20Search). Also check [AutoML](http://www.ml4aad.org/automl/)

Answer (score 0):

So I don't think there is a hard and fast rule for specifying the number of neurons.
I usually use trial and error method. I train my network with a few different architectures until I get good result.

Few things to keep in mind

1. Deeper network take a lot of time to train so try building smaller network. The accuracy and generalization may be less in that case.
2. If you go for deeper network, take care of the gradient vanishing/exploding problem which is quite prevalent in deep networks.

Answer (score -1):

With your network, you are trying to approximate a function F(x_1,x_2,..) mapping from some Input to the 10-dimensional vector of the wine quality.

In your case, the Input can be the 11 features, or maybe just 1. If for example the wine price is a feature, there will definitely be a correlation between price and quality. But this Correlation will probably approximate the "True function" just roughly. So, by incorporating more features in your model, you can approximate the True underlying function better and better. But be aware, that some features could be useless or have almost no influence as well !